# Can a WebView's history be permanently stored?

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in an app in which I use `goBack()` and `goForward()`.
When the app is closed however, the history is cleared. Is there a possibility to store the history or to set it to be permanent for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [WebBackForwardList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebBackForwardList.html) from the WebView and then dump that to a preference.

EDIT: maybe [saveState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [restoreState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState%28android.os.Bundle%29) will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, how can I set the WebBackForwardList to the new instance of WebView so that the history get loaded?

Answer (score -2):

Well the Best Example suits you is `SharedPreference`.

You can get the Current URL of WebView when `onBack()` is gets Executed and get it saved on initialization.

Example of [Preference](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html).

Comment: Thanks but I need to keep track of the whole history, not just the last visited url

Comment: Okie, then i would suggest you have two option 1) Internal Database, 2) ArrayList / HashMap

Comment: I thought of the DB, it would have been nice if I could use the built-in history